# 401 Unauthorized response while connecting to Sitecore CDP from Sitecore Connect Recipe

Tags: cdp, sitecore-connect, recipe

I was able to create connection successfully (using `Client Key` and `API Token`) in Sitecore Connect `recipe` to upload a batch file into Sitecore CDP to create Guest records. But while executing a test, i got below 401 Unauthorized exception like below.

```
401 Unauthorized: {
  "status" : "UNAUTHORIZED",
  "code" : 401,
  "message" : "Authentication credentials are required to access the resource. All requests must be authenticated.",
  "moreInfoUrl" : "https://support.sitecore.com"
} at line: 143
```

[image]

What i am doing wrong here? Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CDP Connection is pointed at the APJ AWS region which isn't valid for your account. The CDP Connector currently doesn't have a "Connection Validation Test" so any values you input into a Connection are considered valid, obviously when you start executing requests with your Recipe if your Connection values are incorrect your Recipe will fail.

I have requested that the CDP Team add such validation to ensure that when you connect a Connection it immediately validates your input.